# Oracle JDBC driver not found

Tags: java, jdbc

I created a simple java program to connect to Oracle that uses the `OracleDriver` class.  The `CLASSPATH` variable is set but I still get `CLassNotFoundException`.

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

Specifics:

```
$echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:.


$jar tf /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar | grep OracleDriver
oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver$1.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriverExtension.class

$java OracleCon
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a folder to your `CLASSPATH`, only folder of classes or resources are expected. In your case, it is a jar file so you have to provide the name of the jar too which means that your `CLASSPATH` variable should rather be set to `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar:.`.

Starting from Java 6, you can also use the wildcard notation to refer to all jar files directly located in a given folder, in your case, your `CLASSPATH` variable could then be `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/*:.`.

More details about [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)

Comment: For further infos: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) is a link to the Oracle pages on "Setting the class path".